# Customize 404 error page

Tags: add-on, sap-commerce-cloud

How can I customize the 404 page in hybris with an addon?

I already tried to make my own DefaultPageController and extend the DefaultPageController but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite a page controller in an addon, you have to add some xml configuration. Here is an example for the ProductPageController:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/accdoc/Customizing+the+Product+Details+Pages

Add this xml snippet to your addons myaddon-web-spring.xml:

```
<bean name="defaultPageController" class="my.package.myaddon.controllers.pages.DefaultPageController"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/">defaultPageController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please add some example. Not everyone has account on wiki.hybris.com.